# socket context provider not working in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, socket.io, react-context

I created a context file, socket.tsx:

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import { io, Socket } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io("http://localhost:3000", {
    reconnectionDelay: 1000,
    reconnection: true,
    reconnectionAttempts: 10,
    agent: false,
    upgrade: false,
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  }),
  SocketContext = createContext<Socket>(socket);

  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("someone connected: ", socket?.id);
  });

const SocketProvider = ({ children }: any) => {
  return (
    <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>{children}</SocketContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { SocketContext, SocketProvider };
```

Then I wrapped my app in the socket provider, app.tsx:

```
return (
    <WagmiConfig client={wagmiClient}>
      <RainbowKitProvider chains={chains} theme={darkTheme()} coolMode>
        <ChakraProvider theme={theme}>
          <SocketProvider>
            <Page>
              <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Page>
          </SocketProvider>
        </ChakraProvider>
      </RainbowKitProvider>
    </WagmiConfig>
  );
```

Finally, I try and access the socket in a component:

```
import { SocketContext } from '../context/socket';

const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { address } = useAccount();
  const [userCount, setUserCount] = useState(0);
  const socket = useContext(SocketContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userCount", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setUserCount(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

This code logs:

```
  socket.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("someone connected: ", socket?.id);
  });
```

but this code does not:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userCount", (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      setUserCount(data);
    });
  }, []);
```

Here is the server:

```
const { Server, Socket } = require("socket.io");
const express = require("express");
const { createServer } = require("http");
const next = require("next");
const { parse } = require("url");
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const user = require("./server/api/userAPI");
const game = require("./server/api/gameAPI");
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

console.log("hello");

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const expressApp = express();
    const httpServer = createServer(expressApp);
    const io = new Server(httpServer);

    expressApp.use(express.json());
    expressApp.use("/user", user);
    expressApp.use("/game", game);

    httpServer.listen(3000, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("> Ready on http://localhost:3000");
    });

    expressApp.get("*", (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    io.on("connect", (socket) => {
      console.log(io.engine.clientsCount);
      socket.broadcast.emit("userCount", io.engine.clientsCount);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

If i move the userCount code to the context file, it logs fine. but it is not working in the component. How can I fix this? Also, the server `io.engine.clientsCount` is logging on the server side but not on the client side.

Update: Tried moving the socket connections to different sites and nothing is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the usEffect to this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("userCount", (data) => {
      setUserCount(data);
    });
  }, [socket]);
```

and doing the socket connection in the context file